# YouTube API 3 GET last videos from specific User

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need help to retrieve YouTube videos from specific user with the new API version.

I've create YouTube Data API on [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com)

**Both OAuth** and **Public API access** for Browser.

Before I was use this code to retrieve the latest 6 video:

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads?max-results=6';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
    $watch = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;
}
```

How can I update this code with API 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been working on a similar thing in .net and its not quite as simple as it used to be.

It now requires a couple of extra steps:

Step 1: you need to get the channelId for the user via:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername={0}&key={1} - where {0} is the USERNAME and key is you API key

Step 2: from that you can get a list of videos via:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId={0}&key={1}

Step 3:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails,player&id={0}&key={1} - where id is the videoId returned from step 2.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi! 
I can't understand if the **3 steps** must be 3 separate request or I can put **all in one** URL request.
After all I obtain an error at the first step. The **USERNAME** is the name of the profile, right? And the **API key** is referred to the Public API access Key generate for Browser?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, yeah its a multistep process, as Ibrahim Ulukaya says below, you might be able to manage it with 2 steps, I know from what I needed it for I had to have three steps.

Comment: Does anyone know how you can return more than 5 entries in Step Two?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer - 2018**

```
<?php
/**
 * Gets the latest YouTube channel video.
 */
class Youtube
{
    /**
     * Channel ID or Channel User.
     *
     * @access private
     * @var string
     */
    private $channel = "";

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     *
     * @param string $channel Channel ID or Channel User.
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct($channel)
    {
        $this->channel = $channel;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the video.
     *
     * @access public
     * @return array
     */
    public function video() : array
    {
        return array( 'title' => $this->getVideo('title'), 'id' => $this->getVideo('id') );
    }

    /**
     * Gets the last video.
     *
     * @param string $property 'title' or 'id'
     * @access private
     * @return string
     */
    private function getVideo($property) : string
    {
        $xml = null;

        if ( @fopen('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=' . $this->channel, 'r') !== false ) {
            $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=' . $this->channel); // Channel User
        } elseif ( @fopen('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=' . $this->channel, 'r') !== false ) {
            $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=' . $this->channel); // Channel ID
        }

        if ($xml !== null) {

            $namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
            $video = $xml->entry[0]->children($namespaces['yt']);

            if ($property === 'title') {
                return $xml->entry[0]->title;
            } elseif ($property === 'id') {
                return $video->videoId;
            }

        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}

$channel = 'UChsXToK8E4U8lqXaabPwlBw'; // Channel ID or Channel User.
$Youtube = new Youtube($channel);
$video   = $Youtube->video();
?>

<h1><?php echo $video['title']; ?></h1>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $video['id']; ?>?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a 2 step process.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos#videos-retrieve-uploads

Step 1: Retrieve the playlist ID for the channel's uploaded videos

Step 2: Retrieve the list of uploaded videos

You can chain these requests. So 2nd request could be 1.requests's callback function.

Comment: Thank you, but can you give me an example?
Is it correct this URL?
`$feedURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername=USERNAME&key={API-KEY}';`