# Can we play our YouTube channel videos in our app?

Tags: java, android, youtube, video-player

Google's official YouTube Video Player has many bugs so I used this 3rd party library.

https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player

This library helped me to use any YouTube video in my app with YouTube videoID, But it loads specific video by it's Id(video URL)
For example

```
  @Override
  public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
    String videoId = "S0Q4gqBUs7c"; <------
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
  }
});
```

Is there any way to load the latest video of our YouTube channel in this YouTube player.

If someone can help me in java code to do this, it will be appreciated, I just want to learn this for better development, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best would be to get the last video Id with the youtube Data-API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)

Here is a related stackoverflow question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393572/10059386)

Comment: You will have to get the latest video id from the api and use it than in the library, as example you could use (https://square.github.io/okhttp/)